# When does React create SyntheticEvents?

Tags: reactjs

Right now, this is the way I understand event handling in React:

1. The native event capture phase happens
2. The native event reaches target
3. The native event bubbles back up
4. React catches it at the `document` layer
5. React puts it in its `EventPluginHub`
6. React simulates another full capture/bubble roundtrip for the `SyntheticEvent`
7. React runs the handlers you built in your code

If my understanding of React internals is correct, and taking into account [this part](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow) of the HTML spec:

> Event objects are dispatched to an event target. But before dispatch
>   can begin, the event object’s propagation path must first be
>   determined.

Does React wait until the event bubbles up to `document` to create its `SyntheticEvent`? And if so, why? In the first step of the event's life, all info about its propagation path is known, so they could do it there.

Comment: Trying to follow up on this here https://github.com/gaearon/overreacted.io/issues/29 if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention in the React source of the reason for waiting for events to bubble in order to dispatch `SyntheticEvent`s (that I can find).

The decision to wait for events that bubble to finish their bubbling before trapping them in the React events system is apparently **only a matter of code organization**.

Reading React's [ReactBrowserEventEmitter](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react-dom/src/events/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js) `listenTo` function, simplified here to make it more easily understandable:

```
for (let i = 0; i < dependencies.length; i++) {
  const dependency = dependencies[i];
  switch (dependency) {

    case: // All event types that do NOT bubble
      trapCapturedEvent(dependency, mountAt);

    default:
      // By default, listen on the top level to all non-media events.
      // Media events don't bubble so adding the listener wouldn't do anything.
      const isMediaEvent = mediaEventTypes.indexOf(dependency) !== -1;
      if (!isMediaEvent) {
        trapBubbledEvent(dependency, mountAt);
      }
      break;

  }
  isListening[dependency] = true;
}
```

The easiest way to separate events that bubble from those that don't (and keep code readable) seems to be to trap events that bubble in their bubbling phase, and those that don't in the capture phase.

So, in summary, the actual way events work (to make an analogy with my initial proposition in the question) is the following:

#### For events that bubble:

1. The native event capture phase happens
2. The native event reaches target
3. The native event bubbles back up
4. React catches it at the document layer with (an abstracted version of) `addEventListener(type, handler, false) // False stands for "catch it in the bubbling phase"`
5. React puts it in its `ReactBrowserEventEmitter`
6. React simulates another full capture/bubble roundtrip for the SyntheticEvent
7. React runs the handlers you built in your code

#### For events that don't bubble:

1. The native event capture phase happens
2. React catches it at the layer in which you set the listener in your code with (an abstracted version of) `addEventListener(type, handler, true) // True stands for "catch it in the capture phase"`
3. React puts it in its `ReactBrowserEventEmitter`
4. React simulates another full capture/bubble roundtrip for the SyntheticEvent
5. React runs the handlers you built in your code

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons is performance. Rather than attaching event listeners to every event you use inside the app, React attaches a single event listener for every event type to `document`. Then, when you create a, for example, `onClick` event on a `div`, it just adds that to it's internal event listener map. Once click on a div happens, React's listener on document node finds your event listener and calls it with SyntheticEvent.

This way, react doesn't have to re-create and clear listeners from DOM all the time, it just changes it's internal listener registry.

The other reason is that React's event bubbling works differently compared to DOM one in some cases. [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) in particular.

Take this for example:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <div onClick={() => console.log('I was clicked!')}>
    MyComponent
    <SomeModalThatUsesPortalComponent>A modal</SomeModalThatUsesPortalComponent>
  </div>
);

const SomeModalThatUsesPortalComponent = () => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div onClick={() => console.log('Modal clicked!')}>this.props.children</div>,
    document.getElementById('myModalsPortal')
  );
}
```

This would end up with following DOM:

```
<body>
  <div>
    My Component
  </div>
  <div id="myModalsPortal">
    <div>A modal</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So in this case when using a Portal, DOM structure doesn't match the component structure exactly. Here is where bubbling behaviour diverges:

- Clicking on `A modal` will *not* trigger a native click event on `MyComponent's` div
- It *will* trigger React's `onClick` handler on `MyComponent's` div, because modal is a child component of `MyComponent`

Comment: You got some great clarifying points there, but not this one: why can't React listen to events on the `document` on the capture phase instead of the bubble phase? It would be earlier.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even though this post is very informative, it doesn't answer the question - I tried answering it myself after some research.

Answer (score 0):

React does top level delegation by adding all the react event handlers on document. So the following happens during capture and bubble phase.

Capturing Phase:

1. capture event listeners on document (Native DOMEvents)
2. capture event listeners on react elements (SyntheticEvents)
3. capture event listeners on children of document  (Native DOMEvents)

Bubbling Phase:

1. bubble event listeners on children of document  (Native DOMEvents)
2. bubble event listeners on react elements (SyntheticEvents)
3. bubble event listeners on document  (Native DOMEvents)